# Why is my custom webform submit handler not submitting?

Tags: webforms, forms

I've looked at a number of posts, but none of them have quite the same issue as I am. I've added two custom submit buttons to a webform (in addition to the default one created by the admin page.) My custom validate function and submit function are being called, but the default submit function is not - i.e. the error logging I've put in my custom function gets printed, but the form is NOT actually submitted. Any ideas?

```
function create_vector_user_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
  case 'webform_client_form_24': // free trial webform
    $form['submit']['64_bit_btn'] = array(
      '#name' => 'op',
      //'#button_type' => 'submit',
      '#type'   => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('DOWNLOAD 64-BIT TRIAL'),
      '#executes_submit_callback' => TRUE,
    );

    $form['#validate'][] = 'create_vector_user_free_trial_form_validate';
    $form['#submit'][] = 'create_vector_user_free_trial_form_submit';
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'create_vector_user_free_trial_form_submit';
    break;
  }
}

function create_vector_user_free_trial_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
// this function runs correctly

}

    function create_vector_user_free_trial_form_submit($form_id, &$form_state) {
    error_log("submit!");
    if (strtoupper($form_state['clicked_button']['#value']) == 'DOWNLOAD 64-BIT TRIAL') {
        error_log("submitted 64");
    }
    else if(strtoupper($form_state['clicked_button']['#value']) == 'EMAIL ME A LINK') {
        error_log("submitted email");
      $to = $form_state['values']['submitted']['email']; 
      $params = array();
      $params['version'] = $form_state['values']['submitted']['download_type'];
      $key = 'homepage';

      drupal_mail('create_vector_user', $key, $to, language_default(), $params);
    }

    else {
        error_log("submitted default 32");
    }

  error_log("test end");

}
```

**ETA:** I've also tried this in my `form_alter` function based on [this article](https://www.drupal.org/node/1291574) about custom validation:

```
$form['#validate'][] = 'create_vector_user_free_trial_form_validate';
// $form['#submit'][] = 'create_vector_user_free_trial_form_submit';
$first = array_shift($form['#submit']);
array_unshift($form['#submit'], $first,'create_vector_user_free_trial_form_submit');
```

//$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'create_vector_user_free_trial_form_submit';

Comment: Is all this code really needed to recreate your issue? Are you sure there aren't any parts you could simply remove, for sake of simplicity, and still have the behavior you want to ask about?

Comment: I don't know! That's why I posted the question. I'm not super-familiar with module development or altering forms. I was following several examples I found online, including the link I posted. What parts do you think are unnecessary?

Comment: Your create_vector_user_free_trial_form_submit function doesn't kill  the process of the submit? I mean, it doesn't have a  die(), or a redirect? if you add a dd("test"); at the very end of your function this test string is printed in the log?

Comment: @Gnuget - I originally had the entire code posted, but someone indicated that I shouldn't post all my code. No, there's no die or redirect in my custom function. I've added the code back to the OP.

Comment: @Gnuget - I also added a test log at the very end of the submit function, outside the if/elseif/else conditional. It's hitting both the "submitted 64" error and the "test end" error. So I can't figure out why the form data isn't submitting.

Comment: question, do you want to doesn't matter which button is clicked the form be submitted? I replicate your problem and if I click the custom button the custom function is executed  but not the form is not subbmited but if I click  the default button the form is submitted correctly but the custom function not.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem.

One of the features of webform is the ability of have multi-page forms, and the way how webform determine if it is in the "final" page is checking if the submit button has the value "Submit" and if that is not the case then it thinks to there is another page to evaluate before to submit the last function.

You can see this in the file webform.module in the line 3174:

```
 // Check for a multi-page form that is not yet complete.
 $submit_op = !empty($form['actions']['submit']['#value']) ? 
 $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] : t('Submit');
 $draft_op = !empty($form['actions']['draft']['#value']) ? 
 $form['actions']['draft']['#value'] : t('Save Draft');
if (!in_array($form_state['values']['op'], array($submit_op,   
$draft_op, '__AUTOSAVE__'))) {
```

In the case of your example `$form_state['values']['op']` doesn't exists and even if it exists it wouldn't has the value 'Submit'  so it  will try to handle your form as a multipage form and It will not execute the last part of the function.

What I did to make your example work was only add the this in your submit function `$form_state['values']['op'] = 'Submit';` and that's it.

It feels like a hack but that is the way how webform work :(

Below the example if you want to compare it with your code:

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function test1_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    switch ($form_id) {
        case 'webform_client_form_5':
            $form['64_bit_btn'] = array(
                '#name' => 'op',
                '#type' => 'submit',
                '#value' => t('DOWNLOAD 64-BIT TRIAL'),
            );
            $form['#validate'][] = 'create_vector_user_free_trial_form_validate';
            array_unshift($form['#submit'], 'create_vector_user_free_trial_form_submit');
            break;
    }
}

function create_vector_user_free_trial_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
    // this function runs correctly
}

function create_vector_user_free_trial_form_submit($form_id, &$form_state) {
     // add your code here
    $form_state['values']['op'] = 'Submit';
}
```

(please note to my module is called test1 you need change this with the name of your module)

Comment: So are you saying the ONLY thing that should be in my submit function is that one line, and my other submit code should go somewhere else? Or do I add that line to the existing submit code?

Comment: Add that line to your existing code, I added a comment in my submit function indicating where your code should  go.

Comment: Thanks. There must be something else going on, then, because it still doesn't submit.

Comment: Try my example and check if I it is working and after that start adding your code in the submit function, It should  work.

Comment: I've removed all my custom code from the submit function, and left just your line. Still doesn't submit.

Comment: The webform's  $form['#submit'] has two callbacks webform_client_form_pages which check if your web form has more than one page and  webform_client_form_submit which actually save the data, please add debug messages in this function to check where the callback stop working because indeed the callback is called but it doesn't process the data, there you will can debug why is stop saving the data, hope this helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29883/discussion-between-gnuget-and-emmys).